# Firebird connection using non-ASCII characters in path

Tags: unicode, connection, firebird

I have my Windows server set to Turkish locale. My Firebird DB exists on a path that includes Turkish characters. This is what my connection sting looks like:

```
"user id=somename;password=somepwd;max pool size=200;min pool size=8;
   connection lifetime=120000;
   initial catalog=E:\\Açğıİîöşüûin\\Metabase\\metabase.fdb;port number=3050;
   data source=127.0.0.1;server type=Default;packet size=8192;charset=UTF8;"
```

I'm using FirebirdClient in C# to connect

When I try to open I get this exception:

> "I/O error during \"CreateFile (open)\" operation for file
>   \"E:\A�giI��s��in\Metabase\metabase.fdb\"\r\nError while trying to
>   open file"

If the Turkish part of the name is ANSI, the DB open works fine.

Any ideas if its possible to get FB to respect the Turkish path name?
Is it possible to use a path name containing anything other than ANSI characters (eg. cyrillic, arabic, UNICODE, UTF8)?

FB version 2.5.2

Comment: Which Firebird version and which Firebird ado.net provider version are you using?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756.aspx  Turkish has different ANSI and OEM codepages. Windows by default assigns OEM codepages for non-graphic applications, like Firebird Server. With regular Win32 application I speculate you could pre-recode the path ANSI->OEM but with DotNet applications using UTF-16 strings I think there is no such option.... Maybe you can try download FirebirdClient sources and hack this hack-around into it and see if it would work

Comment: I'm using FB 2.5.2

Comment: And which Firebird ado.net provider version?

Comment: @Arioch'The The Firebird ado.net provider uses `isc_dpb_utf8_filename`, and the database name is sent as UTF-8; then it is up to Firebird and Windows to do the right thing (and it works when I test it with Firebird 2.5 and higher and the latest ado.net provider.

Answer (score 2):

Historically only ASCII characters are supported, and using characters in the connection character set will also work if that is the same as the OS locale default character set (I believe there are some exceptions, especially with UTF-8 in version before 2.5). Unfortunately, the ADO.net provider always uses UTF-8 for sending the database name.

Since Firebird 2.5 it is possible to use UTF-8 if the database parameter buffer contains the `isc_dpb_utf8_filename` option, and the Firebird ado.net provider does support this extension. So I assume you either use an old version of the Firebird ado.net provider that doesn't support this, or you are using Firebird 2.1 or older.

However looking a bit closer at the path you use, you might run afoul of some of the path normalization Firebird does on Windows to make paths case insensitively comparable. The path in your code is `Açğıİîöşüûin`, but the error message reports `A�giI��s��in` (BTW: on my system I don't have the UTF replacement characters and it shows `AçgiIîösüûin`!), which indicates at least that some normalization was done: `ğ` -> `g`, `ı` -> `i`, `İ` -> `I`, and `ş` -> `s`. For example if I rename the folder to `AçgiIîösüûin` it works even when I use `Açğıİîöşüûin` in my C# code.

That this is related to the path normalization seems to be corroborated by the fact that when I try to open a Firebird 2.5 database with Firebird 3 using path `D:\Temp\Açğıİîöşüûin\testdatabase.fdb`, the resulting error message about an unsupported ODS version reports the path as `D:\TEMP\AÇGIIÎÖSÜÛIN\TESTDATABASE.FDB`

So it looks like you need to be careful with the path used, I suggest you use path with only ASCII, or try to use an alias (but that will probably have the same problem).

It could possibly be a bug in Firebird, but I am not sure about that: it is possible that Windows itself does similar normalization, as the initial error is in the original case, but is normalized. You should consider posting a question to the firebird-devel mailing list.

Comment: ....aliases maybe would bering that problem again, should aliases.conf be filled in ANSI or OEM or UTF-8 codepage? But atleast after fixing it there would be no special requirements for the C# program/provider

Comment: @Arioch'The AFAIK the locale default character set (in the case of Windows the legacy locale default afaik) for Firebird 2.5 and earlier, UTF-8 for Firebird 3, but yeah it is messy.

Comment: Thanks fo all the answers so far.

I find plenty of references to WHAT isc_dpb_utf8_filename option does but HOW to use it. Any ideas?

Comment: @user7399006 As I say in my answer the Firebird ado.net provider uses it automatically, assuming you use a recent version (eg 5.7.0.0).

Comment: @Mark, don't you know if we are supposed to append the `isc_dpb_utf8_filename` option to DPB and pass UTF-8 encoded byte string into API functions like `isc_attach_database` when using C API? I've tried that (for sure with dummy Unicode file path), but I'm getting _"Cannot transliterate character between character sets"_ error from FB.

Comment: @Victoria Consider asking a separate question (although you may want to consider asking on the Firebird-support mailing list). As far as I'm aware that should work, as long as you are connecting to Firebird 2.5 or higher using a Firebird 2.5 or higher fbclient. IIRC you need to add isc_dpb_utf8_filename as an int DPB item with value 1.

Comment: @Mark, passing `isc_dpb_utf8_filename` option I seem to got (it has no value). The problem is how to pass the database name value (how to encode it to byte string) as UTF-8 encoded byte string is rejected with the mentioned error. Well, [here e.g.](https://www.ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/how_to/doc_478) they do not need to encode the string. It's nice to have support for Unicode file names (why to bother with UTF-8 at all) if (almost) nobody knows how :) I'll try to ask on mailing lists (thinking of you as the MVP here for Firebird). Thank you for your extra time!

Comment: @Victoria Thanks :) The problem is that I usually don't use fbclient itself (or only as a secondary API), so I don't know all its ins and outs. Maybe this is helpful: https://www.ibphoenix.com/resources/documents/how_to/doc_478 this suggests that it should be a string DPB item with the database path encoded in UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

use DOS short names with this WIN API function:

```
// Define GetShortPathName API function

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll",
 CharSet = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CharSet.Auto,
 SetLastError = true)]

static extern uint GetShortPathName(string lpszLongPath, StringBuilder shortPath, int shortPathLength);
```

and pass database path as shortPath

`var connectionString = new FbConnectionStringBuilder
 {
  Database = shortPath.ToString(),`